# Multiple Video Files Simultaneously Playing in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-video-player

I had asked the same question for iOS on iPad but now I am trying to see if it's possible within Android.  The response I received so far is no within iOS.  If it's possible in Android please explain what API is used.

Here's my original question referenced:

**[Original Posting on iOS for Multiple Videos Playing Simultaneously on an iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226677/is-it-possible-to-play-multiple-video-files-simultaneously-on-an-ipad-in-either-h/6235467#6235467)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible and it's done through using a VideoView.  I saw it working on a Motorola Droid with 2 videos playing simultaneously.

Creating multiple VideoViews will do the trick.  Details are below in the API.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Comment: Can you please share the code for the Android on multiple video streaming.
I'm kind of the stuck here .. Please help

Answer (score 6):

I tried to do so(2 VideoViews), but only one video played. It is because of linux decoder, which may be used as single instance only(from stack trace info).
For now, to achieve multiple videos playback I try to use FFmpeg as video decoder and OpenGL for render surface. I haven't done it yet, but I think that it will be too heavy operation(play multiple videos). However, I hope this is right direction for you.

I've checked decoder issue and it seems it is linux kernel depended:
I've tested on Nexus One with 2.3.4 and 2.6.35.7-... kernel - it fails.
On second rooted Nexus One with 2.3.4 and 2.6.37.6 linux kernel - it works.
Also check this link:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17802
So, play multiple videos via VideoView possible, but not on all devices(linux kernel depended, I guess).